# Which of painting modes is correct for usual drawing in weight paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting, brushes

In weight paint mode I can draw with higher values:
[image]
but I can't redraw mesh with lower values. As I remember the problem could be in brush blend mode (which is selected to `mix` in my case) but I've tried to use `multiply` and `add` modes without any result.
Which mode is correct for my situation?

In blend mode menu I don't have `draw` option:

[image]

Comment: Reduce the Weight setting. 1 gives maximum weight (fully red). 0 gives zero weight (fully blue). If you draw over the area again with a reduced or zero weight it will reduce the influence.

Comment: @JohnEason it doesn't work.

Comment: It should do! See @moonboots answer below.

Comment: What happens if you switch to Draw (the default) instead of Mix?

Comment: @JohnEason I don't have this option (added it in question), but answer below is correct - I just mixed up strength and weight values.

Comment: Ah ok. It's always a good idea to show the whole Blender window when asking questions. You can take a screenshot in Blender from the Window > Save Screenshot menu in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the *Mix* mode, put the *Weight* at 0 and lower down the *Strength*:

[image]

Here is what it gives when you paint:

[image]

Comment: Nope, it's just doesn't work. And I don't know why.

Comment: please share your file (only the part you show): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have menu with weight and strength at top and I mixed up things because of it. Your answer is correct. I just changed strength without changing weight.

Comment: Right click on the top bar and choose Show Tool Settings

Comment: It's working. Thank you!

Comment: (also available in the N panel > Tool, or first tab of the Properties panel)

Answer (score 1):

Typically when I want to remove weight, I'll do so with a multiply brush.  For a multiply brush to work at full strength, it should have a strength of 1 and a weight of 0.

[image]

There are multiple ways to do this.  I don't think there's any such thing as a correct method here; you use whatever works for you.  However, there is a reason that I tend to use a multiply brush in preference to a subtract, and that is because it gives smoother weights-- weights where the derivative is continuous:

[image]

Starting with a plane displaced by a linear gradient weight, I use a subtract brush on the far and a multiply brush on the near.  You can see that the far plane has a sort of crease, where the final value got clamped to 0, but no such crease on the near plane.

There are other potential ways that a brush might not do what you want it to; there are a lot of settings that would make it not work at all.  But most of those settings would affect brushes that increased weight as much as they would affect brushes that decreased weight.  One way where I've seen people get stuck is, in previous versions of Blender, using a brush with a particular name like Multiply but that brush was actually on Add blend-mode.  The name of a brush, and the blend mode associated with it, are two different things, and the name doesn't really do anything.